# Can I infer linear dependence from the following span relations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, matrix-rank

Consider a $d$-dimensional complex vector space. I have three sets of $d-1$ vectors each for which the following holds:
$\text{span}(v_1,...,v_{d-2},v_{\alpha})=\text{span}(v_1,...,v_{d-2},v_{\beta})=\text{span}(v_1,...,v_{d-2},v_{\gamma})$.

Note that the sets (each composed of linearly independent vectors) only differ in the last vector.

Can I conclude from the conditions above that the set $\{v_{\alpha},v_{\beta},v_{\gamma} \}$ is *linearly dependent*? If so (or not), what is the argument?

Edit: In the problem I am working on, none of the vectors above is orthogonal to any other vector.

Comment: No. Just take $n=3$, $Span\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}=Span\{(1,0,0),(0,-1,0)\}=Span\{(1,0,0),(0,1/2,0)\}$ but $\{(0,1,0),(0,-1,0),(0,1/2,0)\}$ are clearly dependents...

Comment: That's my point. The set is linearly dependent. Is this true for all $d$?

Comment: yes of course...

Answer (score 1):

Take $d=4$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_1&=&(1,0,0,0)\\
v_2&=&(0,1,0,0)\\
v_{\alpha}&=&(0,0,1,0)\\
v_{\beta} &=&(0,1,1,0)\\
v_{\gamma}&=&(1,0,1,0)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The answer is therefore "No" in the most general case. Will it still be no if none of the vectors can be orthogonal? That is the scenario I am in.

Comment: Of course; it is not difficult to adjust this example to make the vector non-orthogonal.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide an example?

Comment: The mental image takes place in $\Bbb{R}^3$, the fourth coordinate is redundant. The first two vectors span a plane. The last three vectors are simply not contained in that plane, and linearly independent. That leaves you a lot of room to choose your own example.

Comment: Vectors $v_1,v_2,v_{\alpha}$ define a unique direction in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is perpendicular to all three of them. Similar thing for $v_1,v_2,v_{\beta}$ and for $v_1,v_2,v_{\gamma}$ . Since their span is the same, these directions must coincide, i.e. $v_{\alpha}$, $v_{\beta}$ and $v_{\gamma}$ must all lie on the same plane, i.e. their form a linearly dependent set. Is anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: @vincyfx Yes; because you are in $\Bbb{R}^4$ the fact that $v_{\alpha}$, $v_{\beta}$ and $v_{\gamma}$ are perpendicular to some direction implies that they are contained in some *hyperplane* in $\Bbb{R}^4$, i.e. some $3$-dimensional subspace. Not a $2$-dimensional subspace. For a clear and simple example of this, consider the direction $(0,0,0,1)$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @vincyfx And for future reference; if you start your comment with `@Servaes` then I will be notified. I only saw your last comment by coincidence.